# Why I'm not able to show the image in Bootstrap tool-tip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using **Bootstrap framework v3.3.0** for my website.

I want to show on image as a tool-tip when user hovers a mouse pointer over the icon. For it I'm having following HTML :

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <div class="input-group">  
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="trans_id" id="trans_id"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" rel="tooltip" data-html="true" title="localhost/img/demo_img.png"></a>    
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code is as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.input-group-addon').tooltip({
    selector: "a[rel=tooltip]"
  })
});
```

On hovering I'm not able to display the image. Now the text I mentioned in title(i.e. The complete image location path is displayed as a tool -tip.)

All the necessary CSS and jQuery files are included.

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The html parameter is a boolean, so you need to set it to true with

```
<a data-html="true" ...etc... >
```

Then you need to use the title to supply yout HTML content:

```
<a data-html="true" title="<img src='...' />" ...etc... >
```

Bootstrap 3 docs for this are here:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-usage

jsfiddle example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/7s81L84m/

Comment: Do I need to write jQuery code too or should I manage with HTML only?

Comment: You can do it all in HTML. That example uses JS, but everything you supply in the JS like {selector: 'foo'} can be done in HTML as data-selector="foo". Just don't forget to include the bootstrap.js file and remember that you need to manually trigger tooltips; see the note about opt-in in the docs.

Comment: Yes, I got your point but suppose I wrote HTML for image that I want to show in tool-tip. But that image will be shown if I write the HTML anywhere on the page. I want to show the image only in a tool-tip. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: ah sorry I am wrong about the selector - you do it in the title. I just experimented with a fiddle, and updated my answer together with the fiddle link.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I already reached there with my attempt. But now having some different trouble. Not able to add the vertical scroll bar to the image that is displayed in a tool-tip.